# How does Perl variable scope work in while loop under strict mode?

Tags: perl, scope

I'm very new to Perl and I'm confused with exactly how its variable scope works.
I'm trying to create an array of Hashes from the result of a MySQL query.

The following code works, as intended, **without** use strict

```
  my %hash = ();

  while (my %hash = %{$qhand->fetchrow_hashref()} ) {
    push(@results, {%hash});
  }
```

but when **strict** is enabled it produces the following error:

*Can't use an undefined value as a HASH reference at [filename] line XX (the line of the while statement).*

Could someone tell me what I'm doing wrong and what the corresponding rule in strict is that I'm flaunting?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're violating the `refs` portion of [strict](http://perldoc.perl.org/strict.html). When you try to use a non-reference value as a reference, Perl wants to create a "symbolic reference", which is usually not what you want although it silently continues the program (probably not "working", but just continuing). By enabling strictures, you catch those cases.

In your example and Jonathan's answer, it looks like you are doing a lot of acrobatics to undo hash references just to make them hash references again. Is there a reason you don't just leave it as a hash reference?

```
while( my $href = $qhand->fetchrow_hashref ) {
  push @results, $href;
  }
```

And, if you just want to get all the results as hash references, there's a DBI method for that so you can skip the `while` loop:

```
my $results_array_ref = $qhand->fetchall_arrayref( {} );
```

Comment: The reason for copying the hashrefs is probably that he`s confused `fetchrow_hashref` with `fetchrow_arrayref`.  The latter keeps returning the _same_ arraryref, so you can't just push them onto an array, or you'll have N copies of the last row.  But `fetchrow_hashref` is documented to return a new hashref each time, so that isn't an issue.

Comment: You're probably correct, i'll fully admit to not being aware of the full extent of my reference folly but it became thus from the need to create a certain data structure for producing json from after this code. I will try your alternatives though, Thank-you.

Answer (score 3):

That's a run time error (after the script has been working for a while), rather than a compile time error, isn't it?

You need to check that the hash ref returned from `$qhand->fetchrow_hashref()` (from Perl [DBI](http://search.cpan.org/~timb/DBI-1.615/DBI.pm)) is valid before converting the hash ref into a hash.  When there are no more rows to fetch, you get back an `undef`, and you can't convert the `undef` into `%hash`.

You also don't want two hashes called `%hash` - either in the loop or not in the loop, but not both.

```
  while (my $href = $qhand->fetchrow_hashref())
  {
      my %hash = %{$href};
      push(@results, {%hash});
  }
```

Comment: You're making two copies of the hashref.  You want `push(@results, \%hash);` or `push(@results, {%$href});`.  And as brian points out, it's not actually necessary to copy the hashrefs at all.

Comment: That part I copied from the question without really bothering to analyze what else was going on; the key point was that the code was dereferencing `undef` and triggering the message.

Comment: Thanks. I'm confused as to why this would be the case in strict mode and not otherwise? Does the undef not cause and error in non-strict mode as it's the same query & same result set?

Comment: I explained everything in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into the same problem so here was the solution I implemented.

```
my %rtn;
my $hr = $handle->fetchrow_hashref;
if($hr)
{
    do
    {
        %rtn=%{$hr};
        ...snip...


        ...snip...
        $hr = $handle->fetchrow_hashref;
    }
    while ($hr);
}
```

Set a scalar ($hr) to the expected reference ($handle->fetchrow_hashref) to test for null (if($hr)) before looping and prior to the cast (%{}), then after done with that reference fetch the next one. Once it ends up being null on the next fetch call that breaks the loop and you carry on with no worries.

Answer (score -7):

I'm not a Perl expert, but it's probably the cast to hash on the function call `$qhand->fetchrow_hashref()`.
If this function already returns a hash, why not just skip the cast?

Comment: The language is "Perl", not "PERL", and it returns a hashref, not a hash.

Comment: if you are not a Perl expert don't waste peoples time with "probably. ..."